# Enabling/disabling a button with jquery.validationEngine

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using [this](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) jQuery form validator but I cannot understand how to make one simple thing here: if form is not valid disable the submit button, otherwise enable submit button.

A little bit of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#registration_form").validationEngine({
        //
    });
});
</script>

<?php
echo "<form id=\"registration_form\">";

echo "<label for=\"name\">Name</label>";
echo "<input class=\"validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[3,100]]\" id=\"name\"><br />";

echo "<button type=\"submit\" id=\"submit_button\">GO</button>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#registration_form").validationEngine(
    {
        inlineValidation: true
        });
    $('.change').change(function() {
        validate();
    });
    validate();
     });
     function validate(){
     var res = $.validationEngine.loadValidation("#name");
     if (!res)
         $("#submit_button").attr('disabled',''); 
     else
         $("#submit_button").attr("disabled","disabled"); 
 }
 </script>
```

in the body

```
<input class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[3,100]] change" 
   id="name" value=""><br />
```

try and feedback me

Comment: Hmm, I don't see how this could help me :) I'm trying to enable or disable a button in my form.

Comment: This is correct. If you change some value you have to re-validate the form. Please remove -1

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping! However, your solution is not working :( I've tried it myself and was expecting to button enables/disables but in this case, button is ALWAYS disabled... Cannot figure out why :( Plus, all errors are showing on page load...

Comment: This is how to desire. I try it

Comment: Hey Davide, thank you very much for your effort! Now we are near my solution! :) First of all I needed to change `change(function()` into `keyup(function()` because I want to enable my button immediately after user starts typing something in input field. I still have 2 'small' problems; first is that I need to validate few input fields in my form, not only the 'name'... Should I create a variable for each of my input fields and then check if all of them are valid or is there a way to check them all at once?

Comment: mah... second problem is solved, don't worry :) thanks for helping, i will mark this as an answer ;-)

Comment: I used this case for studying the validation engine. I used this plugin a months ago but in a standard way

Comment: `loadValidation()` is no longer supported by `jquery.validationEngine`

Comment: Good answer JackTheKnife